# How to change the breakpoint icon color in the validation/marker bar (on the right side of the editor)

Tags: android-studio

The vertical validation/marker bar on the right side of the Android Studio editor contains breakpoint, error, and TODO markers. Unfortunately, the breakpoint and error markers are the same color and wastes time sifting out the errors from the breakpoints. I would like the breakpoint markers to be a different color or hidden altogether. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the marker colors in Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General, by changing the color selected in the "Error stripe mark" field.

Comment: Thanks for the response - it helped me find how to change the Breakpoint icon color. It can be done in Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | Debugger | Breakpoint line. Be sure to save any current read only (Default) scheme under your customized scheme first or the Error stripe mark will be disabled.

Comment: The location of the setting changed (AS 3.2.1): `File - Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - General - Errors and Warnings` for changing the color of the text within the editor or of the stripe mark in the sidebar. You can also change the mark in the sidebar: `File - Settings - Editor - General - Error stripe mark height` ("0" disables it). To change the color for specific errors/warnings ("inspections") or remove the markers for them: `Right-click the sidebar - Customize Highlighting Level - Configure inspections` - deselect everything you don't want to get a warning about.